# How do I put my laptop into sleepmode after a given time?

Tags: python, sleep, sys

So I'm writing this code to put my laptop in sleep mode after a given amount of time. Weird thing is, when the program wants to execute the last line of code it points out that there's a syntax error at `os`.

I've tried putting a simple instead print command (as a test) that also ends up as a syntax error.  I've tried the command inside `os.system()` directly and that works.

The python version I use is 3.7.2.

```py
import time
import sys
import os
counter = 0
for x in sys.argv:
    counter+= 1

if counter== 2:
    seconds = sys.argv[1]

else:
    seconds =  sys.argv[2]+60*sys.argv[1]
time.sleep(int(seconds)
os.system('Rundll32.exe Powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState Sleep')
```

I expect the script to put my PC into sleep mode after x seconds or after x minutes, y seconds (dependent on parameters).

This is how I enter the command in CMD:

```
python file.py x (y)
```

Yes I'm in the correct folder to do so.

Comment: You're missing a `)`

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're doing this with Python instead of just configuring your OS to do the same? Is this a learning exercise? For "real world" use your OS can probably do a much better job.

Comment: @SLaks well, that's a stupid mistakethznks for pointing it out

Comment: @Chris I wanted something that put pc into sleep after I entered the amount of time for when i'm watching Netfllix from far away, since the screen is big enough. I tried python since I'm learning the language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@SLaks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34397/slaks) pointed out:

> You're missing a `)`

However, I see something very odd in your code, and that's this part of the code:

```
counter = 0
for x in sys.argv:
    counter+= 1

if counter== 2:
    seconds = sys.argv[1]

else:
    seconds =  sys.argv[2]+60*sys.argv[1]
```

You don't need to loop through `sys.argv` to find out its **length**, you can use`len()`!

Like this:

```
seconds = int(sys.argv[1]) if(len(sys.argv) == 2) else (int(sys.argv[2])+60*int(sys.argv[1]))
```

Comment: I'd like to add some 'int()'

`int(sys.argv[1]) if(len(sys.argv) == 2) else (int(sys.argv[2])+60*int(sys.argv[1]))`

Comment: @Andreas You're right, that's actually needed. Updated it.